# "No extension able to load"

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I would like to add a configuration entry to my AppBundle (using Symfony 3.0.3).

### What I'm stuck on:

In spite of efforts I made trying to stick to the documentation examples and looking for fixes on SO, I still get the following Exception and could not yet spot what is wrong.

> InvalidArgumentException in YamlFileLoader.php line 368:
>   There is no extension able to load the configuration for "app"
>   (in /.../src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection
>   /../Resources/config/config.yml). Looked for namespace "app", found none

Threads/articles exist but none suggested solution that actually fixed it for me. Some details may stick out a mile, I hope someone will spot those right away as I spent hours on that.

---

### What I've done so far:

I first set up this **conf file**
I guess "app" key should be okey as the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#manually-registering-an-extension-class#creating-an-extension-class) expects the name to be the lowercased bundle name with the *bundle* part stripped out. Right ?

```
# AppBundle/Resources/config/config.yml
app:
    paginator:
        items_per_page: 3
```

I then set up php classes needed for the loading/setup process, inside the DependencyInjection namespace…

**The Configuration class File:**

```
# /src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface  
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('app');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('paginator')
                    ->performNoDeepMerging()
                    ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
                    ->children()
                        ->integerNode('items_per_page')
                            ->defaultValue(5)
                            ->isRequired()
                            ->cannotBeEmpty()
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end();
        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

**Extension class file:**
Named accordingly to the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#manually-registering-an-extension-class#creating-an-extension-class).

```
# /src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/AppExtension.php
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;

class AppExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {

        $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
            $container,
            new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config')
        );

        $loader->load('config.yml');

        $processor     = new Processor();
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $processor->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    }
}
```

The stack trace

```
in YamlFileLoader.php line 368
at YamlFileLoader->validate(array('app' => array('paginator' => array('items_per_page' => '3'), 'mailer' => array('sender_name' => 'no-reply', 'sender_address' => '%mailer_user%'))), '/../project/src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/config.yml') in YamlFileLoader.php line 338
at YamlFileLoader->loadFile('/../project/src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/config.yml') in YamlFileLoader.php line 44
at YamlFileLoader->load('config.yml') in AppExtension.php line 21
at AppExtension->load(array(array()), object(ContainerBuilder)) in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 55
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 39
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in Compiler.php line 107
at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in ContainerBuilder.php line 545
at ContainerBuilder->compile() in Kernel.php line 477
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->boot() in Kernel.php line 166
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app_dev.php line 30
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I did not really understand the whole process. Let's clear things a little bit.

> The goal is to expose services and give dev the ability to customize arguments/dependencies.

If that's not what you meant, browse SO, *truth is out there*.
This kind of bundle configuration really makes sense when you wish to publish your bundle. AppBundle is not likely to be shared. I personally wanted to skill up.

---

Loaded config file(s) should contain public services declarations.  It may have some parameters set as well.
If you want to set array like properties, declare "flattened" parameters keys. Container's parameterBag is not wise enough to traverse array trees. so `$this->getParameter('my_bundle.foo_array.sub_key')` will not result in retrieving `$parameters['mybundle']['foo_array']['sub_key']`, but `$parameters['my_bundle.foo_array.sub_key']` instead.

```
# AppBunble/Resources/config/config.yml
parameters:
    # Prepending a custom namespace may help keep things clearer but is not required
    my_ns.foo_property: "@foo_service"
    my_ns.bar_property: "bar_value"
    my_ns.array_key.baz_property: "baz_value"
    my_ns.array_key.qux_property: "qux_value"
```

You can declare the usual way and indent subkeys (with yaml), but in this case it has to be "flattened" within your bundle's Extension class (see below).
Those parameters might serve as default value to configure services.

```
# AppBunble/Resources/config/services.yml
services:  
    app.my_service:
        class: AppBundle\Services\MyService
        arguments: ['%my_ns.foo_property%', {"address" : '%ns.array_key.baz_property%', "name":'%ns.array_key.qux_property%'}]
```

At this point you have parameters and services declared, split or not between several files, inside `MyBunble/Resources/config/*`

Then what ? Since you exposed services, dev people using your bundle may wish to provide alternative configuration. Your job is to make it possible inside of your bundle's *Extension* class *(eg. AppBundle/DependencyInjection/AppExtension.php )*. Everything takes place inside the *load* method.

- Your default params have to be gathered and injected into the container (with helpers like Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader,or ..XMLFileLoader, …).

  ```
  $loader = new YamlFileLoader( $container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config') );
  $loader->load('config.yml');
  // ...
  $loader->load('services.yml');
  ```
- The first parameter **array $configs** holds our bundle's public options overrides. Its content comes from app main "config" files. User may set options inside both config.yml and config_dev.yml, then $configs will expose 2 entries. Anyway, $configs is where you have to look for some options potentially set by developpers.

  ```
  app:
      foo_property: 'some value'
      array_key:
        qux_property: "jd@mydomain.com"
  ```
- In case it is not empty, it has to be validated with the help of a Configuration class ( eg. AppBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php ).

  ```
  $configOverride = $this->processConfiguration( new Configuration() , $configs);
  ```
- The Configuration class.

  ```
  namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

  use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
  use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

  class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface  
  {
      public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
      {
          $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
          $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('app');

          $rootNode
              ->children()
              // ...
              ->end();
          return $treeBuilder;
      }
  }
  ```

  "app" is the root key symfony expects to find in order to populate `AppExtension::load` `$configs` parameter. By convention it is a snake-cased version of the bundle's name, minus the "bundle" suffix. It can be customized but you'll have some methods overrides to set, for more infos [see documention](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#manually-registering-an-extension-class).
- Once custom options have been validated, you may merge with your defaults,  transform, overwrite, or whatever. In the end, you need to set the resulting options set as container parameters. These options will be used as soon as the container try to instantiate your services.

  ```
  class AppExtension extends Extension
  {
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {

      $loader = new YamlFileLoader( $container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config') );
      $loader->load('config.yml');
      // Merging datas…
      $container->setParameter('app', $resultingConfig);
      $loader->load('services.yml');
  ```

Note: I'm using Sf 3.0.3.
I hope this will help.